# Why drawing pixels directly is slower than drawing data in a BufferedImage?

Tags: java, swing, drawing, pixel, bufferedimage

Currently I'm trying to create something to display a "2D view" for a Grid which can be used for various proporses, such as a simple 2D game.

After doing a wrap work with a simple Core class (this holds all information to my visual stuff, including pixels values for sprites) I started the visual work. As my aim is to do this with plain swing/awt in Java I just created a custom `JComponent` to this.

In my `JComponent` I tried some approaches and decided to test draw my pixels info in a `BufferedImage` and at other hand draw the pixels directly in Graphics object.

Looking through internet I found some ways to draw a pixel/dot on screen, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43236741/4563960). In this case, I wrapped this in a method:

```
    private void drawSpritePixels(ArrayList<Spr.Pixel> pixels, int startX, int startY, Graphics2D g) {
        for (Spr.Pixel p : pixels){
            g.setColor(p.color);
            g.fillRect(p.x + startX, p.y + startY, 1, 1);
        }
    }
```

For drawing my data onto a `BufferedImage`, I'm using this:

```
    public BufferedImage spriteImage(int spriteAddress) {
        BufferedImage img = GraphicsEnvironment
                .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
                .getDefaultScreenDevice()
                .getDefaultConfiguration()
                .createCompatibleImage(32, 32, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
        for (Pixel p : getSpriteInfo(spriteAddresses.get(spriteAddress))) {
            img.setRGB(p.x, p.y, p.color.getRGB());
        }

        return img;
    }
```

As title says, the performance was better using `BufferedImage` approach.  Im my tests `BufferedImage` takes 40ms to finish while Pixels takes 200ms+ to the same amount of "work".

Then, why this is so different? Should do I avoid any iterations in pixels approach?

Comment: `BufferedImage` is a piece of memory, and writing to memory is fast.  Setting a pixel directly is writing to the screen, and is slower.  I suspect that writing a whole block of pixels, as when displaying a `BufferedImage` will be faster than writing those pixels individually.  It is an obvious way to speed up screen processing.

Comment: Then we can say that the difference is that ```BufferedImage``` acts as just 1 operation while the pixels approachs acts as many operations (one for each pixel drawn)?

Comment: Probably something like that.  It may be as simple as retrieving a subroutine from slow memory once rather than multiple times.