# repaint method after add custom JPanel to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

I have this code, but `JPanel` repaint method does not work.  If I do that after add it to JFrame class  I debug it and it does not recall `paintComponent`.

Why is that so?

```
package trial;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


class jp extends JPanel
{
     int i=0;

     {
        setBackground(Color.RED);
     }

     @Override
     protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
     { 
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Color[] c={Color.red,Color.green};
        //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        g.drawLine(i, i, i+100, i+100);
        i+=50;
     }
}

public class Trial extends JFrame{

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Trial f=new Trial();
       jp a;
       a=new jp(); 
       System.out.println(a.i);
       f.add(a);
       f.setVisible(true);
       f.setSize(500, 500);
       f.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);

       a.repaint();

   }
}
```

Comment: why do you have two {{ in the protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {{ ... }}

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: I just tested it on my machine, setting a debug point in the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method and the program got into debug mode as expected.

Comment: it's got into it , but not by method "repaint" my note is about the method repaint why it does not make any sense

Comment: Some links (that *may* be helpful):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902974/why-is-paintcomponent-never-called-by-repaint, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676187/why-is-paint-paintcomponent-never-called

Answer (score 0):

**[UPDATE]** to fit the question better:
A call to `repaint()` places a `PaintEvent` into the *Event Queue*. This `PaintEvent` will be handled by another thread, the *Event Dispatching Thread*.

In short: the `paintComponent()` is called in another thread as your main method.

**[/UPDATE]**

I am not sure what you're trying to achive but try this at the end of your `main` method:

```
    try {
        while (true) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            a.repaint();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
```

Is a moving line like this what you're expecting? The reason why this is working: As far as I recall, Java Swing may collapse multiple repaint requests that are enqueued in the *Event Dispatching Thread* into a single paint request - which is probably what you experienced. In my example above, waiting 1 second is enough to get distinct repaints.

**Nevertheless I strongly advise you not to use my (or your) code**. Reason: The value of `i` depends on the number of calls to paintComponent - which can vary. For example, pull at a corner to resize the window - repaint maybe gets called dozens of times then!

Perhaps you want a `javax.swing.Timer` to periodically update the value of `i` and then trigger a repaint?

Comment: me question is " why "a.repaint" in last line of my code in main does not recall "paintComponent" method ?

Comment: It seems that you need some basic understanding of Java Swing. See my update above.