# How to make new picture when mouse dragged in java

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I want to create a program that can use mouse to move picture around the program here is my code. My code is set position of shape with tempX and tempY that I set it to get position of mouse while draging when drag mouse a picture will move along mouse.
* I can't make this picture repaint while draging mouse anything I miss?
* Add chagnePositionVectors()

```
public class SiaemsiMouse extends JPanel implements MouseListener,MouseMotionListener {

int tempX = 330;
int tempY = 95;

// position of Siaemsi box
int posX[] = {tempX-30,tempX-30,tempX-30};
int posY[] = {tempY+305,tempY+80,tempY+55};

// position of Siaemsi stick
int posXS1[] = {tempX,tempX,tempX-3,tempX+8,tempX+20,tempX+17};
int posXS2[] = {tempX+20,tempX+20,tempX+17,tempX+28,tempX+40,tempX+37};
int posXS3[] = {tempX+40,tempX+40,tempX+37,tempX+48,tempX+60,tempX+57};
int posXS4[] = {tempX+60,tempX+60,tempX+57,tempX+68,tempX+80,tempX+77};
int posXS5[] = {tempX+80,tempX+80,tempX+77,tempX+88,tempX+100,tempX+97};
int posXS6[] = {tempX+100,tempX+100,tempX+97,tempX+108,tempX+120,tempX+117};
int posXS7[] = {tempX+120,tempX+120,tempX+117,tempX+128,tempX+140,tempX+137};

// All of y for stick are equals
int posYS1[] = {tempY,tempY,tempY-10,tempY-15,tempY-10,tempY};

public SiaemsiMouse(){
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
    addMouseListener(this);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SiaemsiMouse siaemsimouse = new SiaemsiMouse();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(siaemsimouse);
    frame.setSize(800,600);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics){
    super.paintComponent(graphics);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) graphics;
    Random random = new Random();

    // Draw Siaemsi
    Ellipse2D.Double floor = new Ellipse2D.Double(posX[0],posY[0],200,50);
    Rectangle2D.Double body = new Rectangle2D.Double(posX[1],posY[1],200,250);
    Ellipse2D.Double top = new Ellipse2D.Double(posX[2],posY[2],200,50);
    g2.setPaint(Color.RED);
    g2.fill(floor);
    g2.fill(body);
    g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
    g2.fill(top);

    // Draw siaemsi's stick
    Rectangle2D.Double stick1 = new Rectangle2D.Double(posXS1[0],posYS1[0],18,100);
    GeneralPath path1 = new GeneralPath(GeneralPath.WIND_EVEN_ODD,posXS1.length);
    path1.moveTo(posXS1[1],posYS1[1]);
    for (int i = 2; i < posXS1.length; i++) {
        path1.lineTo(posXS1[i],posYS1[i]);
    }
    path1.closePath();

    Rectangle2D.Double stick2 = new Rectangle2D.Double(posXS2[0],posYS1[0],18,100);
    GeneralPath path2 = new GeneralPath(GeneralPath.WIND_EVEN_ODD,posXS2.length);
    path2.moveTo(posXS2[1],posYS1[1]);
    for (int i = 2; i < posXS2.length; i++) {
        path2.lineTo(posXS2[i],posYS1[i]);
    }
    path2.closePath();

    Rectangle2D.Double stick3 = new Rectangle2D.Double(posXS3[0],posYS1[0],18,100);
    GeneralPath path3 = new GeneralPath(GeneralPath.WIND_EVEN_ODD,posXS3.length);
    path3.moveTo(posXS3[1],posYS1[1]);
    for (int i = 2; i < posXS3.length; i++) {
        path3.lineTo(posXS3[i],posYS1[i]);
    }
    path3.closePath();

    Rectangle2D.Double stick4 = new Rectangle2D.Double(posXS4[0],posYS1[0],18,100);
    GeneralPath path4 = new GeneralPath(GeneralPath.WIND_EVEN_ODD,posXS4.length);
    path4.moveTo(posXS4[1],posYS1[1]);
    for (int i = 2; i < posXS4.length; i++) {
        path4.lineTo(posXS4[i],posYS1[i]);
    }
    path4.closePath();

    Rectangle2D.Double stick5 = new Rectangle2D.Double(posXS5[0],posYS1[0],18,100);
    GeneralPath path5 = new GeneralPath(GeneralPath.WIND_EVEN_ODD,posXS5.length);
    path5.moveTo(posXS5[1],posYS1[1]);
    for (int i = 2; i < posXS5.length; i++) {
        path5.lineTo(posXS5[i],posYS1[i]);
    }
    path5.closePath();

    Rectangle2D.Double stick6 = new Rectangle2D.Double(posXS6[0],posYS1[0],18,100);
    GeneralPath path6 = new GeneralPath(GeneralPath.WIND_EVEN_ODD,posXS6.length);
    path6.moveTo(posXS6[1],posYS1[1]);
    for (int i = 2; i < posXS6.length; i++) {
        path6.lineTo(posXS6[i],posYS1[i]);
    }
    path6.closePath();

    Rectangle2D.Double stick7 = new Rectangle2D.Double(posXS7[0],posYS1[0],18,100);
    GeneralPath path7 = new GeneralPath(GeneralPath.WIND_EVEN_ODD,posXS7.length);
    path7.moveTo(posXS7[1],posYS1[1]);
    for (int i = 2; i < posXS7.length; i++) {
        path7.lineTo(posXS7[i],posYS1[i]);
    }
    path7.closePath();

    g2.setPaint(new Color(153,153,0));
    g2.fill(stick1);
    g2.fill(path1);
    g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
    g2.draw(stick1);
    g2.draw(path1);
    g2.setPaint(new Color(153, 76, 0));
    g2.fill(stick2);
    g2.fill(path2);
    g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
    g2.draw(stick2);
    g2.draw(path2);
    g2.setPaint(new Color(255, 255, 0));
    g2.fill(stick3);
    g2.fill(path3);
    g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
    g2.draw(stick3);
    g2.draw(path3);
    g2.setPaint(new Color(0, 255, 128));
    g2.fill(stick4);
    g2.fill(path4);
    g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
    g2.draw(stick4);
    g2.draw(path4);
    g2.setPaint(new Color(102, 0, 56));
    g2.fill(stick5);
    g2.fill(path5);
    g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
    g2.draw(stick5);
    g2.draw(path5);
    g2.setPaint(new Color(255, 0, 127));
    g2.fill(stick6);
    g2.fill(path6);
    g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
    g2.draw(stick6);
    g2.draw(path6);
    g2.setPaint(new Color(224, 224, 56));
    g2.fill(stick7);
    g2.fill(path7);
    g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
    g2.draw(stick7);
    g2.draw(path7);

}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    changePositionVectors(e.getX(),e.getY());
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

}
public void changePositionVectors(int xPos, int yPos){
    tempX = xPos;
    tempY = yPos;
    repaint();
}
}
```

Comment: `"My code is ...."` -- you need to tell us what problems your current code is having. Otherwise, how will we know how to help you?

Comment: I forgot about it. I want to make it can repaint while drag mouse to new position.

Comment: That's not a question or statement of your problem, but rather is a desire. We need to know how your code isn't working, what steps you've taken to debug your problem, and in as clear and succinct a manner as possible a description of *exactly* where you're stuck.

Comment: @boxed__l: -1 for your comment. You ***never*** call `paintComponent(...)`. He is calling `repaint()` which is sufficient since this will suggest too the repaint manager to start the painting cascade. Please delete your comment.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels But isn't op's move logic inside paintComponent() ? Shouldn't repaint() have called this? done

Comment: I try to set new position with tempX that will get values while drag mouse and paint new picture where mouse dragged. I can get position of mouse with try-print their value so their value can set in mouseDragged method. But I can't make repaint(); work. Is repaint() can't use with pantComponent()?

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676187/why-is-paint-paintcomponent-never-called)

Comment: @boxed__l: all of his Shape creating and moving code should be moved outside of paintComponent. Instead this method should only paint the Shapes.

Answer (score 2):

I see what I think is your problem.

- You are assuming that if you change tempX and tempY that all variables that are derived from them will change as well,
- but this is not so. Any variables created with tempX or tempY will not magically know to change once they have been created.
- You need to change any variables that need to be changed yourself, and the easiest way to do this is to create a method that takes your tempX and tempY values and re-calculates all the other fields that need to be recalculated.
- Consider creating and moving your Shape and path objects **outside** of paintComponent, perhaps in the Mouse adapter code and simply painting the Shape in paintComponent.

i.e.,

```
public void changePositionVectors(int xPos, int yPos) {
  // set the fields that need to be set with x and y
  repaint();
}
```

---

**Edit**
Regarding your new code:

```
public void changePositionVectors(int xPos, int yPos){
    tempX = xPos;
    tempY = yPos;
    repaint();
}
```

This fixes nothing since all this does is set's tempX and tempY, and again, changing these values will not magically change any value that was originally created with these fields. Again, your changePositionVectors method must contain more code that in fact sets the values of all the vectors needed for drawing your GUI.

---

**Edit** I would take a completely different tack from what you and boxed are doing. I would:

- Draw everything to a BufferedImage
- Place that BufferedImage into an ImageIcon
- Place that ImageIcon into a JLabel
- Place that JLabel into a JLayeredPane
- Add a MouseListener and MouseMotionListener to the JLabel.
- Done.

For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SimpleDrawing {
   private static final int PREF_W = 780;
   private static final int PREF_H = 570;
   private static final int GAP = 1;
   private static final int BI_WIDTH = 200 + 2 * GAP;
   private static final int BI_HEIGHT = 300 + 2 * GAP;
   private static final int ELLIPSE_WIDTH = BI_WIDTH - 2 * GAP;
   private static final int ELLIPSE_HEIGHT = 50;
   private static final Color CAN_COLOR = Color.red;
   private JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane() {
      public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
         return SimpleDrawing.this.getPreferredSize();
      };
   };
   private JLabel imageLabel;
   private Point imageLabelPoint = new Point();

   public SimpleDrawing() {
      layeredPane.setOpaque(true);
      layeredPane.setBackground(Color.white);

      imageLabel = drawImageLabel();
      imageLabel.setLocation(imageLabelPoint);
      imageLabel.setSize(imageLabel.getPreferredSize());

      layeredPane.add(imageLabel, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

      MyMouseAdapter myMouseAdapter = new MyMouseAdapter();
      imageLabel.addMouseListener(myMouseAdapter);
      imageLabel.addMouseMotionListener(myMouseAdapter);
   }

   private JLabel drawImageLabel() {
      BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(BI_WIDTH, BI_HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      g2.setColor(CAN_COLOR);
      int x = GAP;
      int y = BI_HEIGHT - ELLIPSE_HEIGHT - GAP;
      int width = ELLIPSE_WIDTH;
      int height = ELLIPSE_HEIGHT;
      g2.fillOval(x, y, width, height);

      y = GAP + ELLIPSE_HEIGHT / 2;
      width = ELLIPSE_WIDTH;
      height = BI_HEIGHT - ELLIPSE_HEIGHT / 2 - GAP - y;
      g2.fillRect(x, y, width, height);

      g2.setColor(Color.black);
      y = GAP;
      height = ELLIPSE_HEIGHT;
      g2.fillOval(x, y, width, height);

      g2.dispose();
      ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);      
      return new JLabel(icon);      
   }

   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   public JLayeredPane getLayeredPane() {
      return layeredPane;
   }

   private class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
      private boolean dragging = false;
      private Point srcLoc;
      private Point msePressLoc;

      @Override
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
         if (e.getButton() != MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            return;
         }

         dragging = true;
         srcLoc = ((Component) e.getSource()).getLocation();
         msePressLoc = e.getLocationOnScreen();
      }

      @Override
      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
         if (e.getButton() != MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            return;
         }

         dragging = false;
         moveTo(e);
      }

      @Override
      public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
         if (!dragging) {
            return;
         }
         moveTo(e);
      }

      private void moveTo(MouseEvent e) {
         Point loc = e.getLocationOnScreen();
         Component comp = (Component) e.getSource();
         int x = loc.x - msePressLoc.x + srcLoc.x;
         int y = loc.y - msePressLoc.y + srcLoc.y;
         comp.setLocation(x, y);
         layeredPane.repaint();
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      SimpleDrawing simpleDrawing = new SimpleDrawing();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple Drawing");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(simpleDrawing.getLayeredPane());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: should I put in mouseDragged() like this?                                       p    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        changePositionVectors(e.getX(),e.getY());
    }

Comment: I call chagePositionVector() from mouseDragged() but it can repaint the picture.

Comment: Thank you for your help ^^. Finally it can move like I thought. Seem that I still need to improve my code about graphics and image. :D

Answer (score 2):

Try this, here based on @HovercraftFullOfEels's comment I have separated moving from the `paintComponent()`...

**EDIT 1:**
Added floor, body and top objects. Throws null pointer exception on O/P screen but works

**EDIT 2:**
Still shows NPE, Fixed: Image(a cake) was not moving as posX,posY,... arrays were not updated

```
class SiaemsiMouse extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    private int tempX = 330;
    private int tempY = 95;
    // position of Siaemsi box
    private int posX[] = {tempX - 30, tempX - 30, tempX - 30};
    private int posY[] = {tempY + 305, tempY + 80, tempY + 55};
    // position of Siaemsi stick
    private int posXS1[] = {tempX, tempX, tempX - 3, tempX + 8, tempX + 20, tempX + 17};
    private int posXS2[] = {tempX + 20, tempX + 20, tempX + 17, tempX + 28, tempX + 40, tempX + 37};
    private int posXS3[] = {tempX + 40, tempX + 40, tempX + 37, tempX + 48, tempX + 60, tempX + 57};
    private int posXS4[] = {tempX + 60, tempX + 60, tempX + 57, tempX + 68, tempX + 80, tempX + 77};
    private int posXS5[] = {tempX + 80, tempX + 80, tempX + 77, tempX + 88, tempX + 100, tempX + 97};
    private int posXS6[] = {tempX + 100, tempX + 100, tempX + 97, tempX + 108, tempX + 120, tempX + 117};
    private int posXS7[] = {tempX + 120, tempX + 120, tempX + 117, tempX + 128, tempX + 140, tempX + 137};
    // All of y for stick are equals
    private int posYS1[] = {tempY, tempY, tempY - 10, tempY - 15, tempY - 10, tempY};

    public SiaemsiMouse() {
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SiaemsiMouse siaemsimouse = new SiaemsiMouse();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(siaemsimouse);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    //added objects here
    private Rectangle2D.Double stick1, stick2, stick3, stick4, stick5, stick6, stick7;
    private GeneralPath path1, path2, path3, path4, path5, path6, path7;
    //added more objects 
    private Ellipse2D.Double floor;
    private Rectangle2D.Double body;
    private Ellipse2D.Double top;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) graphics;
        super.paintComponent(graphics);     //If you use paintComponents() the previous image persists
        //Random random = new Random(); //No use for Random??

        // Draw Siaemsi
        g2.setPaint(Color.RED);
        g2.fill(floor);
        g2.fill(body);
        g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g2.fill(top);

        g2.setPaint(new Color(153, 153, 0));
        g2.fill(stick1);
        g2.fill(path1);
        g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g2.draw(stick1);
        g2.draw(path1);
        g2.setPaint(new Color(153, 76, 0));
        g2.fill(stick2);
        g2.fill(path2);
        g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g2.draw(stick2);
        g2.draw(path2);
        g2.setPaint(new Color(255, 255, 0));
        g2.fill(stick3);
        g2.fill(path3);
        g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g2.draw(stick3);
        g2.draw(path3);
        g2.setPaint(new Color(0, 255, 128));
        g2.fill(stick4);
        g2.fill(path4);
        g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g2.draw(stick4);
        g2.draw(path4);
        g2.setPaint(new Color(102, 0, 56));
        g2.fill(stick5);
        g2.fill(path5);
        g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g2.draw(stick5);
        g2.draw(path5);
        g2.setPaint(new Color(255, 0, 127));
        g2.fill(stick6);
        g2.fill(path6);
        g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g2.draw(stick6);
        g2.draw(path6);
        g2.setPaint(new Color(224, 224, 56));
        g2.fill(stick7);
        g2.fill(path7);
        g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g2.draw(stick7);
        g2.draw(path7);         
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        changePositionVectors(e.getX(), e.getY());
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
    public void changePositionVectors(int xPos, int yPos) {
        tempX = xPos;
        tempY = yPos;

        //calc pos...        
        posX = new int[]{tempX - 30, tempX - 30, tempX - 30};
        posY = new int[]{tempY + 305, tempY + 80, tempY + 55};
        // position of Siaemsi stick
        posXS1 = new int[]{tempX, tempX, tempX - 3, tempX + 8, tempX + 20, tempX + 17};
        posXS2 = new int[]{tempX + 20, tempX + 20, tempX + 17, tempX + 28, tempX + 40, tempX + 37};
        posXS3 = new int[]{tempX + 40, tempX + 40, tempX + 37, tempX + 48, tempX + 60, tempX + 57};
        posXS4 = new int[]{tempX + 60, tempX + 60, tempX + 57, tempX + 68, tempX + 80, tempX + 77};
        posXS5 = new int[]{tempX + 80, tempX + 80, tempX + 77, tempX + 88, tempX + 100, tempX + 97};
        posXS6 = new int[]{tempX + 100, tempX + 100, tempX + 97, tempX + 108, tempX + 120, tempX + 117};
        posXS7 = new int[]{tempX + 120, tempX + 120, tempX + 117, tempX + 128, tempX + 140, tempX + 137};
        // All of y for stick are equals
        posYS1 = new int[]{tempY, tempY, tempY - 10, tempY - 15, tempY - 10, tempY};

        floor = new Ellipse2D.Double(posX[0], posY[0], 200, 50);
        body = new Rectangle2D.Double(posX[1], posY[1], 200, 250);
        top = new Ellipse2D.Double(posX[2], posY[2], 200, 50);

        // Draw siaemsi's stick
        stick1 = new Rectangle2D.Double(posXS1[0], posYS1[0], 18, 100);
        path1 = new GeneralPath(GeneralPath.WIND_EVEN_ODD, posXS1.length);
        path1.moveTo(posXS1[1], posYS1[1]);
        for (int i = 2; i < posXS1.length; i++) {
            path1.lineTo(posXS1[i], posYS1[i]);
        }
        path1.closePath();

        stick2 = new Rectangle2D.Double(posXS2[0], posYS1[0], 18, 100);
        path2 = new GeneralPath(GeneralPath.WIND_EVEN_ODD, posXS2.length);
        path2.moveTo(posXS2[1], posYS1[1]);
        for (int i = 2; i < posXS2.length; i++) {
            path2.lineTo(posXS2[i], posYS1[i]);
        }
        path2.closePath();

        stick3 = new Rectangle2D.Double(posXS3[0], posYS1[0], 18, 100);
        path3 = new GeneralPath(GeneralPath.WIND_EVEN_ODD, posXS3.length);
        path3.moveTo(posXS3[1], posYS1[1]);
        for (int i = 2; i < posXS3.length; i++) {
            path3.lineTo(posXS3[i], posYS1[i]);
        }
        path3.closePath();

        stick4 = new Rectangle2D.Double(posXS4[0], posYS1[0], 18, 100);
        path4 = new GeneralPath(GeneralPath.WIND_EVEN_ODD, posXS4.length);
        path4.moveTo(posXS4[1], posYS1[1]);
        for (int i = 2; i < posXS4.length; i++) {
            path4.lineTo(posXS4[i], posYS1[i]);
        }
        path4.closePath();

        stick5 = new Rectangle2D.Double(posXS5[0], posYS1[0], 18, 100);
        path5 = new GeneralPath(GeneralPath.WIND_EVEN_ODD, posXS5.length);
        path5.moveTo(posXS5[1], posYS1[1]);
        for (int i = 2; i < posXS5.length; i++) {
            path5.lineTo(posXS5[i], posYS1[i]);
        }
        path5.closePath();

        stick6 = new Rectangle2D.Double(posXS6[0], posYS1[0], 18, 100);
        path6 = new GeneralPath(GeneralPath.WIND_EVEN_ODD, posXS6.length);
        path6.moveTo(posXS6[1], posYS1[1]);
        for (int i = 2; i < posXS6.length; i++) {
            path6.lineTo(posXS6[i], posYS1[i]);
        }
        path6.closePath();

        stick7 = new Rectangle2D.Double(posXS7[0], posYS1[0], 18, 100);
        path7 = new GeneralPath(GeneralPath.WIND_EVEN_ODD, posXS7.length);
        path7.moveTo(posXS7[1], posYS1[1]);
        for (int i = 2; i < posXS7.length; i++) {
            path7.lineTo(posXS7[i], posYS1[i]);
        }
        path7.closePath();

        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's error so I change to create shape in constructor but it still nothing.

Comment: @อ๋อมซะอย่าง: if your code does not work or shows an error, you must show your updated code and your errors in your question. 1+